# frigidaire gallery electric range cfef388jeb1

Tags: electrical

I had a power outage and now my Frigidaire electric range is making a screeching sound no lights on the knows or oven temperature  model   CFEF388JEB1

Can anyone help

Comment: I take it neither the oven nor the elements heat?  Also, where in the range is the screeching coming from, roughly?

Comment: Age of range? Does it have an analog clock?

Comment: I looked this up it's a fairly new model. I would call tech support or if it's still under warranty give them a call.